# C# .NET Core property of type ILogger

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I am working on some legacy code and found a property that is of type ILogger. I am assuming that "ILogger" is an interface, so it should probably be used in an inheritance context. What does it mean if the type of the property itself is an interface type?

```
public static ILogger Logger
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            var logOptions = new MyLoggerClassOptions()
            {
                Host = "LOG_SERVER_IP",
                Port = "LOG_SERVER_PORT"
            };
            var provider = new List<ILoggerProvider>() { new MyLoggerLoggerProvider(logOptions) };
            var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(provider);
            return loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ILogger>();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean that "the type of the class itself is an interface type"? Can you poinpoint the part of the code this refers to?

Comment: This is not a class definition, it's a property definition (that should exist inside of a class definition).

Comment: It means that the property returns an object implementing that interface, in this case an object returned via `LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<T>`.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, a property definition indeed. But what it means is still unclear to me, I still can't understant what it means to bu used outside of the inheritance context. I updated the question with the correct nomenclature.

Comment: Is your question about the call to `CreateLogger<ILogger>` or is it about the `public static ILogger Logger` property itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't specific to .NET Core, but to the C# language itself. I suggest you read the [Microsoft article on interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/) for a more thorough understanding of how they work.

But to answer your question, when the type of an object is an interface, all you know about the object is that you can use all the methods of that interface. For example, the [`ILogger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger?view=aspnetcore-2.2) interface requires that a [`Log`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger.log) method is implemented. So you can be sure that you can call `Log()` on that object.

It *might* have more features than what just the interface requires, but you can't use them unless you know what the underlying type is and cast to that type. For example, if you know that the object returned is a [`ConsoleLogger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.console.consolelogger), and you want to access the [`DisableColors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.console.consolelogger.disablecolors) property, then you can do this:

```
((ConsoleLogger) Logger).DisableColors = true;
```

But that will throw an exception if `Logger` is not `ConsoleLogger`.

The usefulness of interfaces is evident in how it's used for loggers. You can pass around an `ILogger` to different parts of your code, without every part of your code having to know *how* stuff is being logged. You can also swap out different types of loggers easily: You can switch from `ConsoleLogger` to [`EventLogLogger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.eventlog.eventloglogger), or make your own `SendToTheMoonLogger`, without having to change any of the code that actually writes to the log.

Answer (score 1):

So there is only one question here:

*What does it mean if the type of the property itself is an interface type?*

In answer to your question an interface is a contract essentially, it says that any class can be used for this property as long as it has specific methods or properties.

Eg if my interface was:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar(string thingy);
}
```

then my actual class would be something like:

```
public class DoDaFoo : IFoo
{
    public void Bar(string thingy) 
    {
        /// do something
    }
}
```

but then I could also use a different class:

```
public class SomeNonsense : IFoo
{
    public void Bar(string thingy)
    {
        /// do something different
    }
}
```

And this is all still valid, we are just using a different class to fulfill the IFoo contract.

So what it actually means is that the property mentioned `Logger` will always return a class that has specific methods or properties and these are defined in the interface `ILogger`, but in theory it could be any class as long as it implements all the mthods in the interface.

More reading

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-interface

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces

https://code-maze.com/csharp-interfaces

Or just google 'c# what is an interface'